# StackOverFlow complete notifier

Tags: feature-request, favorites-notifications

I am looking for a complete stackoverflow notifier. Complete means:

- New questions arrived on our favorite tags
- Reputation change
- New badges
- New comments
  etc.........

No problem, if it is a browser plugin (preferable, and preference to chrome, so that it can be used in windows and linux) or desktop notifier.

I have seen some notifiers, but all lacks some other features.

Some track new questions, but not reputation change or comments etc.

Some track comments etc,while not questions. That is why i am asking for a 'complete notifier'.

**And why question notifier ?** It is because my favorite tags (opencv etc) have less questions a day, so i prefer notifying me of a new question than i looking for a new question all the day.

Comment: I am looking for such a tool too. That would be very handy.